# jquery post form and variables together

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I used this Code to send a form + a variable to a php-script.

```
function upload() {
  var test = "test";
  var infos = $('form').serialize() + '&' + test;
  $.post("ajax.php", { infos: infos }).done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
  });
}
```

now the PHP-Code:

```
$data = $_POST['infos'];
echo $data;
```

returns: formfield1=value1&formfield2=value2&formfield3=value3&test

All values are in this variable...
But how i can use them seperatly with PHP?

For example:

```
$data = $_POST['formfield1'];
```

didn't worked :(

Comment: [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). It will return you with array of objects that contain 2 properties: name and value. You can then parse it and pass it as data.

It could look like this

```
var formdata = = $('form').serializeArray();
var infos = { };
for (var i = 0; i < formdata.length; i++) {
    infos[formdata[i].name] = formdata[i].value;
}

// To add separate values, simply add them to the `infos`
infos.newItem = "new value";

$.post("ajax.php", infos).done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Then in PHP, you'll retrieve values using `$_POST["formfield1"]`.

Comment: Simply add them to the infos object `infos.testItem = "test"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to `explode` them with -

```
$data = $_POST['infos'];
$form_data = explode('&', $data);
$posted_data = array();

foreach ($form_data as $value) {
    list($key, $val) = explode('=', $value);
    $posted_data[$key] = $val;
}

var_dump($posted_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parse_str` method to convert the query string into an array.

In your case, you can do something like this:

```
parse_str($_POST['infos'], $data); // $data['formfield1'], $data['formfield2'], $data['formfield3'] have the values you need
```

More details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 0):

//   here is the jquery part

```
 function upload() {
      var test = "test";
      var infos = $('form').serialize() + '&' + test;
      $.post("ajax.php", { infos: infos },function (data) {
        alert(data); // the fetched values are alerted here.
      });
    }
```

//the php part is here

```
$data = $_POST['infos'];
$field_seperator='&';
$val_seperator='=';
$form_data_val=explode($field_seperator,$data);
    foreach($form_data_val AS $form_vals){
       $vals=explode($val_seperator,$form_vals);
       echo $vals[1];// here the value fields of every form field and the test is fetched.
    }
```

try this .